# Как можно подлкючить андроид устройство к компьютеру и обменивать файлами програмно

Tags: java, android

Как подлюкчить  через usb шнур телефон к компьютеру и записывать туда данные или считать оттуда даннеы компьютер windows телефон android oneplus

Comment: Можно например через сеть. То есть на на пк или устройстве использовать общие папки. Так же можно поднять что-то... (точно не знаю как называется) пример x-plore когда вы заходите через браузер и работаете с файловой системой.

Comment: Воткнуть кабель в телефон. Другой конец воткнуть в компьютер. Вуаля, можно передавать данные.

Answer (score 1):

В android-sdk входит утилита adb, отвечающая за общение компьютера с телефоном. У нее есть команды для копирования файлов с телефона и обратно через командную строку. Организовать автоматический обмен файлами не очень удобно, но вполне реально

Answer (score -1):

Задача у вас довольно сложная и нетривиальная. Как бы я решал эту проблему:

1. Взял бы в руку кабель, нашел бы на нем разъем microusb/usb-type-c и вставил  его в разъем в телефоне. Нашел бы второй разъем usb и вставил бы его в порт  usb в ПК.
2. Дальше на телефоне высветится диалоговое окно с выбором типа подключения: зарядка, передача файлов, и наверное будет что-то типа передача фото/ MTP устройство.
3. Выбираете передачу файлов.
4. Заходите в "Мой компьютер" или в любой другой файловый менеджер и у вас там будет новый диск с названием устройства.
5. Заходим в этот диск и видим внутреннюю (+ внешнюю ) память вашего телефона.
6. Дальше находим нужные вам для переброса на телефон файлы и перетаскиваем их в внутреннюю память телефона, либо нажимаем правой кнопкой мышки и выбираем пункт копировать, дальше переходим в память телефона и при нажатии правой кнопки выбираем пункт вставить.

Представим на минутку что у вас нет кабеля но файлы ооочень нужно перебросить на телефон. Тогда у нас есть два простых варианта: [Wi-Fi](https://www.wideanglesoftware.com/blog/3-ways-android-wifi-file-transfer.php) или [Bluetooth](https://www.technipages.com/transfer-files-between-android-windows-10-via-bluetooth). Надеюсь что один из предложенных мною вариантов вам поможет.

Comment: Спрашивают, как программно это сделать

Comment: @КириллМалышев, в вопросе четко написано через шнур, я и ответил)) так же в моем ответе указано что можно использовать программы для обмена данными.